# Convert 'for' loop with conditions to matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab

I am currently using a nested 'for' loop to calculate an average value. This is an image with 3527*256 pixels, each pixel containing 448 values. I wish to multiply these 448 values with the array called 'modis_rsr'(448*8), then sum only the zero and positive values. After that, I wish to divide this sum by the sum of the values of 'modis_rsr' corresponding to only those with positive values in hyp_1nm.

As you would expect, this sequence is taking too long, and I wish to use a matrix multiplication to speed things up. The only thing I don't know how to do is to include the conditional sum for 'modis_rsr'. I was thinking of creating a reference array to store the indices of those which were negative. But that also seems computationally intensive.

```
for j = 1:8
    for k = 1:256
        for i = 1:3527
            RLs = 0;
            for jj = 1:448
                if hyp_1nm(i,jj,k)>= 0
                    RLi = hyp_1nm(i,jj,k)*modis_rsr(jj,j);
                    RLs = RLs + RLi;
                    temp_rsr(jj,j) = modis_rsr(jj,j);
                else
                    temp_rsr(jj,j) = 0;
                end
            end
            Rs = sum(temp_rsr(1:448,j));

            % Write basr
            basr(i,j,k) = RLs/Rs;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: By saying each pixel contains 448 values, you mean you have e 3 dimensional matrix that has 3527*256*448 size. Right? If you reply back I may be able to help you.

And for the sake of simplicity don't use variable names that may confuse anyone that will read your code (including yourself). Instead of using jj, use another letter or a word.

Comment: Hi Tayyib, thanks for the reply. Yup, it is a 3D array. Sorry about the bad variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't multiply arrays along one particular dimension with matlab**, so you can't avoid using loop in this case. But you can reduce the number of loop by using the logical indexing and the element-wise multiplication.

```
    for j = 1:8
        for k = 1:256
            for i = 1:3527
                RLs = 0;
                ind = hyp_1nm(i,:,k) >= 0; %by using the logical indexing you can avoid 1 loop.
                RLs = sum(hyp_1nm(i,ind,k).*modis_rsr(ind,j)'); % .* = element-wise multiplication
                temp_rsr(ind,j) = modis_rsr(ind,j);
                temp_rsr(~ind,j) = 0;
                Rs = sum(temp_rsr(1:448,j));
                basr(i,j,k) = RLs/Rs;
            end
        end
    end
```

If really you want to avoid for loop, you can use the function `bsxfun`, but `bsxfun`only hide the foor loop, it don't linearize your code.

Comment: Wow the logical indexing is quite useful. Thanks!